# Ir para uma outra activity a partir de um item da lista com dados do site parse.com

Tags: android, listview, parse

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer para chamar uma outra activity, através de um item da lista onde os dados são utilizados do site parse.com.
Por exemplo, tenho esse código:

```
public class ListViewAdapterPizzarias extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;
private ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapterPizzarias(Context context,
                                List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView nome;
    TextView telefone;
    TextView endereco;
    TextView status;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return worldpopulationlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_pizzarias, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        holder.endereco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.endereco);
        holder.telefone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
        holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
        view.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews

    holder.nome.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getNome());
    holder.endereco.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getEndereco());
    holder.telefone.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getTelefone());
    holder.status.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getStatus());


    ///teste
    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

   //O que colocar aqui para buscar o dado do site parse.com e chamar a outra activity?

        }
    });
    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: Sua dificuldade está em saber como criar uma tarefa com *AsyncTask* para chamar o serviço, como passar algo de uma *Activity* para outra ou o que exatamente?

Comment: @Paulo Rodrigues. Eu tenho uma activity que contem uma listview que tem seus dados armazenados no site parse.com. O problema é que tenho uma activity com o nome das pizzarias em uma lista e tenho também uma activity com o cardápio de cada pizzaria. Daí o que acontece é que não consigo associar os dados que são puxados do parse.com para chamar a activity correta. Por exemplo, uma lista com vários nomes de Pizzarias: PIZZARIA CAPRICHO chama activity CARDÁPIO CAPRICHO e PIZZARIA FAT chama activity CARDÁPIO FAT...

Answer (score 0):

Não é interessante você realizar essa lógica dentro do seu Adapter. A partir do seu ListView você tem o método `setOnItemClickListener` que é a melhor maneira de executar uma ação a partir do click em um item da lista.

Para você iniciar uma Activity você precisa de outra Activity para criar um `Intent` e usar o método 'startActivity()', por exemplo:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyNewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Se você estiver utilizando o seu ListView em um Fragment utilize o método `getActivity()` para criar o Intent, por exemplo:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MyNewActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Vê a pergunta acima que eu comentei. Vê se vc entende.

Comment: Acho que entendi o que você precisa. Vou te explicar uma forma de implementação para um cenário como o seu, porém a sua pergunta é muito ampla, não há como explicar tudo aqui. Se você tem uma Activity com dados carregados em uma lista a partir de um Server, muito provável que você monte esta lista com classes (Models no padrão MVC) e cada Model tem um identificador (ID, Código, Etc). Quando ocorre o click em um item da lista você pode pegar o seu Model através do método que eu mencionei, setOnItemClickListener, e assim você chama outro serviço passando o identificador do seu Model.

Comment: Você não teria nenhum exemplo parecido com o que eu estou tentando fazer? Da forma que você falou eu já entendi, o que falta é ver como eu poderia fazer esta implementação.

Comment: Não há como escrever tudo aqui. Você pode ver como funciona estudando um projeto parecido, por exemplo: https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, é isso mesmo que estou procurando, estou resolvendo o problema, caso dê certo, marcarei como resolvido, ainda estou implementando ao meu problema. Obrigado.